# Volley request doesn't execute and no data are fetched

Tags: android, networking

I have a simple URL that fetches some pics from pixabay website. with this URL: https://pixabay.com/api/?key=15507399-305bf88eb0892f7cdf58fb66b&image_type=photo&pretty=true&q=yellow+flowers.
Clicking on the link it is shown the JSON response. I want to get the "id" and "largeImageURL". but the method doesn't even execute. the Arraylist that is supposed to contain the values is always size = 0.
I have added the
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`
I have no clue what I'm missing here

```
 requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    loadImages();

    //testing
    String[] names = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < images.size(); i++) {
        names[i] = images.get(i).getId();
    }
}

private void loadImages() {
    String url = "https://pixabay.com/api/?key=15507399-305bf88eb0892f7cdf58fb66b&image_type=photo&pretty=true&q=yellow+flowers";
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                JSONArray hits = response.getJSONArray("hits");
                for (int i = 0; i < hits.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject pics = hits.getJSONObject(i);
                    images.add(new Flowers(pics.getString("id"), pics.getString("largeImageURL")));
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ha", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("test", "Error", error);
        }
    });
    requestQueue.add(request);
}
```

Comment: After debugging, it turns out that the Images array is adding data from the connection but once the method is done the array is empty. 
'String[] names = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < images.size(); i++) {
        names[i] = images.get(i).getId();
    }' this one here the images size is 0
even tho images inside the method has 20 elemnts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working except that the placement of the block of codes '//testing' is at the wrong location resulting in size = 0. It takes time for the data to come in before 'onResponse()' get triggered and stores the data in 'images'. But you are already accessing the 'images' before 'onResponse()'.

Comment: I tried using repositor-LiveData-ViewModel AKA MVVM architecture. and I passed t images array throughout the hierarchy to the main activity and passed the images array to the recyclerView Adapter via the constructor. still, the issue persists. the images array is null.

Comment: The original concept worked imo. If you want to access the images outside the 'onResponse()', declare a class variable and point to that response in 'onResponse(JSONObject response)'. Try fixing the original problem first before bring in more variables (aka MVVM) to add to the confusion.